# How to use the native storage in ionic 5

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, storage, native, ionic5

I hope you're all right, I need some help. So here it is, in my application I've made a function that when you press a button, allows you to change the theme from light to dark. It works very well but when you restart the application, the theme automatically returns to light. Do you know how I could record (I guess the string theme) with ionic's native storage?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx'
import { EmailComposer } from '@ionic-native/email-composer/ngx';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab3',
  templateUrl: 'tab3.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab3.page.scss']
})
export class Tab3Page {
theme:string = "light";

  constructor(public nativeStorage:NativeStorage, private emailComposer: EmailComposer) {}

  switchTheme(){
    if(this.theme=='light'){
      document.body.classList.add("dark");
      this.theme="dark";
      console.log(this.theme)
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("dark");
      this.theme='light';
      console.log(this.theme)
    }
  }

  sendEmail() {
    let email = {
      to:'my-mail',
      subject: 'My Feedback',
      isHtml: true 
    };

    this.emailComposer.open(email);
  }

}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Your Case.

1.You need to have a Default Theme and then let's say light is the default.

2.Store the theme in a sotrage whenever you change it :

```
let themeSet = 'light';
this.nativeStorage.setItem('storedTheme', {theme: themeSet})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
```

3. Retrieve the storedTheme value in ngOnInit lifecycle event.

   ```
   ngOnInit {
      this.nativeStorage.getItem('storedTheme')
      .then(
        data => console.log(data),//set theme here
       error => console.error(error)
     );}
   ```

4.Change theme Switch Method to parameterized input setTheme Method :

```
  setTheme(theme){
    if(theme=='dark'){
      document.body.classList.add("dark");
      this.theme="dark";
      //save in storage
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("dark");
      this.theme='light';
      console.log(this.theme)
    }
  }
```

call this same method in step two to set theme when you get the theme from Storage setTheme(theme)

5.In Html use the following

```
    (click)="theme=='light'? setTheme('dark'):setTheme('light')"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your sructured answer but I'm blocking a little :/ I think I've done everything right in my typescript file but I have a little problem to call the function in the html file: (click)="setTheme()" "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.". I don't understand what argument I have to enter

Comment: hey now since  setTheme(theme) takes an input of theme variable hence in HTML you would have to do the following.      (click)="theme=='light'? setTheme('dark'):setTheme('light')"; I have also edited the solution 5th step

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me!

Comment: Glad I can help.

Answer (score 0):

You have NativeStorage injected -- just use that.

From the official doc:

```
this.nativeStorage.setItem('myitem', {property: 'value', anotherProperty: 'anotherValue'})
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );

this.nativeStorage.getItem('myitem')
  .then(
    data => console.log(data),
    error => console.error(error)
  );
```

See here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm just asking for help to use the native storage because I don't understand the documentation!